# Почему появляется ошибка conflicting server name on "0.0.0.0:80"?

Tags: nginx

Настраивал один сервис у него в в мануале вот такие настройки nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name selfservice.ru 192.168.16.166;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5003;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                }
}
```

Необходимо было настроить на сервере самописный сертификат, по одному [мануалу](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins) настроил вот так:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/cert.key -out /etc/nginx/cert.crt
```

Новые настройки nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name selfservice.ru;
    return 301 https://selfservice.ru$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name selfservice.ru;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/selfservice/access.log;
    error_log            /var/log/nginx/selfservice/error.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://localhost:5003;
    
    }
}
```

После перезапуска nginx, получаю вот такую ошибку в статусе:

```
Jun 16 18:06:13 srv systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jun 16 18:06:13 srv nginx[3844]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "selfservice.ru" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Jun 16 18:06:13 srv nginx[3855]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "selfservice.ru" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Jun 16 18:06:13 srv systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

В теме не силен, подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно настроить.

Comment: Данная ошибка появляется если прописать server_name с одним портом на listen в разных секциях server. Возможно, в разных файлах. Для проверки выведите `nginx -T` он покажет полный конфиг используемый сервером.

Comment: Поддерживаю два или более конфигов на одно доменное имя. Ищите правьте лишнее убирайте.

Comment: Скорее всего редактор оставил временный файл, а nginx его нашёл и прочитал.